# Clickonce missed out folder in bin

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Hi how do i publish the files from my bin folder using clickonce?

i successfully copied a folder of .sql script to the bin folder using the Build Events `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\..\project.Sql\AlterProductionServer" "$(TargetDir)\AlterProductionServer" /i /y`

My purpose for doing that is to ask the system to check for any database script changes on startup. The system will check the scripts from the bin folder. The reason i xcopy to the bin so that when deploy, my client pc will read it from the same location too. If found, then it will run the .sql scripts to update the database first before running the system.

However, when i clicked on Publish - > Application Files, i do not see the AlterProductionServer  folder which contain .sql files that i have already copied to the bin appear for me to choose to `Include`.

please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing via ClickOnce from within the Visual Studio IDE, it will only offer files from the project/solution, not from the file system. You could add your .sql file to the project, set the build action to `Content` and specify that it be copied to the output directory. This removes the need for your xcopy build action and makes VS aware of the importance of the file.

If it will still not show in the Application Files section after a rebuild, you may have to look at the prospect of writing your own application/deployment manifest files (XML) and using the command-line ClickOnce utilities to publish your solution. I found this was necessary when including items in my ClickOnce distribution which were not dependencies of the main project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But i would like to have the whole folder and its content copied to the output. when i right click the properties for my folder which contains all the .sql script, i do not see the "Copy Always". i can only copy always the scripts inside that folder. If this is so, then the system will have hard time searching for those script.

Comment: thanks Actually the `Content` is already able to copy the whole folder with the script inside. thanks for this

Comment: One question, if by setting the build action to `Content` and set `Copy Always` to copy those script with folder to the bin folder, can the system identify those scripts folder location after deployed using clickonce as this ?` private string databaseUpdatePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\AlterProductionServer";`

Comment: Provided they are being included in the deployment, their original folder structure will be preserved, so you can refer to them using paths relative to the install location, yes.